# Бессоюзное сложное предложение:

Tags: бсп

Немцы хорошо пристрелялись, минометами и пулеметами повредили орудия.

БСП однородного состава?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где вы здесь увидели бессоюзное сложное предложение? Здесь у нас простое предложение, осложненное однородными сказуемыми.